# Set JTextArea to a jasper report

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, ireport

Currently I am working on a reporting module. There we use jasper reporting to display report. I use IReport software to create the report design. I want to know whether i can set a Scroll-able JtextArea to a jasper report. The problem is that I have a large file and I want to show the content of that file in the final jasper report.
Thank You

Nuwan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try checking the Print When Details Overflows and Stretch With Overflow properties. This will expand the fields in question to fit all the data you are trying to put in them.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not supported directly in [Jaspersoft iReport Designer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html), you may be able to leverage the [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) [printing support](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/swing.html).